# what is necessary to run avd with an arm64-v8a image on a linux server

Tags: android, linux, continuous-integration, android-virtual-device, huawei-mobile-services

some processor characteristics

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Model name:                      Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz
```

when I start the avd, I get an error:

```
PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.
```

--

if I run an avd with an image with architecture is x86_64, then I cannot install the latest version of hms_core on it...(((

```
HMS_Core_6.3.0.327.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have Huawei devices to test your apps, It is recommended that you use [Cloud Debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/agconnect/cloud-adjust?ha_source=hms1) of AppGallery Connect to test your app for Huawei Devices.